# Python - TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written some code:

```
def ICP(x):
    numofrepeat=0
    warning=0
    while numofrepeat<len(str(x)) or (x[numofrepeat]==2) or (x[numofrepeat]==3) or (x[numofrepeat]==5) or (x[numofrepeat]==7):
        if (x[numofrepeat]==0):
            warning=warning+1
        if warning>1:
            numofrepeat=len(x)+1
    if warning>1:
        return("false")
    else:
        return("true")
```

After running it, Python gives me an error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

What should I do?

I know, that:

The result of   ICP(121)    is true.
The result of   ICP(999)    is false.

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
ICP(999)
  File "<location>", line 5, in ICP
if (x[numofrepeat]==0):
```

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
    enter code here

Comment: give us the line of error please

Comment: Read [ask] then [edit] the question to give a [mcve].

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    ICP(999)
  File "C:/Users/tomek/Desktop/PYTHON/LOGIA 09 ETAP 2 ZADANIE 3 icp x.py", line 5, in ICP
    if (x[npw]==0):

Comment: What do you pass into the function to cause the error? I bet it's an integer.

Comment: @Levon , yes, it should be an integer

Comment: @Lafexlos - for example if x=5245 and numberofrepeat=2 then x[numberofrepeat] = 4 (it is indexed from 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem should seem clear enough from the error:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Objects of type `int` are neither iterable nor *subscriptable*. I really don't know why you want to index `x` since you're apparently passing an integer.

You can simply test the integer directly:

```
x==2 or x==3 or x==5 or x==7
```

And if `x` is an integer with more than one digit, and you intend to test a digit at an order, you can do:

```
x_str = str(x)
x_str[numofrepeat]=='2' or x_str[numofrepeat]=='3' or x_str[numofrepeat]=='5' or x_str[numofrepeat]=='7'
```

With this conversion to string, `x` becomes *subscriptable*, and indexing works as long as `numofrepeat` is not greater or equal to the length of `x`.

Comment: thanks, but now everything is true, for example: ICP(9873245) is
'true'

Comment: @tom790 Well, the problem with the error has been solved but making your function work as expected is not in the scope of the question: *TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable* .

Comment: so thanks. I voted for your answer, but: ! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: You don't actually need to vote for the right answer, though you can. You just accept it as the right one. That you can do as the original poster despite less than 15 reputation. Also, if he answered your original question please consider posting a new question rather than editing the answered one.

Comment: @tom790 why should the volunteers on SO be working to *your* timescales? Why don't you spend that 90 minutes trying to solve your own problems?