# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable - Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pascals-triangle

I am trying to solve the Pascal's triangle problem in python3 but keep getting **TypeError 'int' object is not subscriptable** everytime.

Here, the question is: **Given a non-negative integer** *numRows*, **generate the first** *numRows* **of Pascal's triangle**.

```
class Solution:
    def generate(self, numRows: int) -> List[List[int]]:
        pascal = []

        for i in range(numRows):
            pascal.append([])
            for j in range(i+1):
                if j == 0 or j == i:
                    pascal.append(1)
                else:
                    pascal[i].append(pascal[i - 1][j - 1] + pascal[i - 1][j])
        return pascal
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38144503/python-typeerror-int-object-is-not-subscriptable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is incorrect:

```
pascal.append(1)
```

it should be:

```
pascal[i].append(1)
```

Otherwise the next row you compute tries to index `1[j - 1]`.  Once fixed, for an argument of `10`, I get the return value

```
[[1], [1, 1], [1, 2, 1], [1, 3, 3, 1], [1, 4, 6, 4, 1],
[1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1], [1, 6, 15, 20, 15, 6, 1],
[1, 7, 21, 35, 35, 21, 7, 1], [1, 8, 28, 56, 70, 56, 28, 8, 1],
[1, 9, 36, 84, 126, 126, 84, 36, 9, 1]]
```